# python InputDevice fflush

Tags: python, keyboard, flush, fflush, evdev

I use python-evdev library for detect keyboard event.

But I have a problem, I need flush the keyboard event after I have detect key.

example:

```
from evdev import InputDevice, categorize, ecodes

dev = InputDevice('/dev/input/event1')
for event in dev.read_loop():
    if event.type == ecodes.EV_KEY:
         print(categorize(event))
         #to do..............
         >>>flush here> KEYBOARD EVENT>>
```

how fflush  dev ?

Comment: I have a similar problem, the input device I'm listening to publishes events way too fast, and they start queuing up. I'd like to flush events after every read.

Answer (score 2):

After doing your stuff with your event, use *device.read_one()* to read all the ones in the queue (*read_one()* returns *None* if the queue is empty).

```
for event in device.read_loop():
    do_stuff_with_your_event(event)
    while device.read_one() != None:
        pass
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on why this answer is a valid answer and do some minor formatting of your code to make it look aligned to the left for readability?